# applying a function rowwise inside mutate(dplyr)

Tags: string, dplyr

I have the below data where Duration captures number of years in the same house, for each household.
Input df:

```
House_ID    Duration
H29937  30 YEAR
H2996   30 YEAR
H156    25 YEAR
H10007  5 MONTH
```

I am trying to get the duration in months with the below query: If the second part of extracted string is YEAR, convert the number in duration to months by multiplying it with 12,
else just take the numeric part of Duration

```
info_df <- mutate(info_df,
                    residence_Months = ifelse(str_split(Duration," ",2)[[1]][2] == "YEAR",
                                                            as.numeric(str_split(Duration," ",2)[[1]][1])*12,
                                                              as.numeric(str_split(Duration," ",2)[[1]][1])))
```

Expected output df:

```
Agent_Code  Duration    Residence_Months
S1299317    30 YEAR     360
S1299622    30 YEAR     360
S1299656    25 YEAR     300
S1300067    5 MONTH     5
```

However, the code above, gives the same value for all rows as 360.

I am not sure where the error is occuring. Can someone please help me with this?

Note : I have tried the rowwise option as pointed out in other posts but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your full data set, this may be better achieved with the `lubridate` package, but taking into account your example, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(House_ID = c("H29937", "H2996", "H156", "H10007"),
             Duration = c("30 YEAR", "30 YEAR", "25 YEAR", "5 MONTH"))

df %>% 
  separate("Duration", c("duration", "unit")) %>% 
  mutate(duration = as.integer(duration),
         Residence_Months = ifelse(unit == "YEAR", duration * 12, duration))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   House_ID duration unit  Residence_Months
#>   <chr>       <int> <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1 H29937         30 YEAR               360
#> 2 H2996          30 YEAR               360
#> 3 H156           25 YEAR               300
#> 4 H10007          5 MONTH                5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @FMM. This works beautifully. Wasn't aware of separate being used in this way. Thanks!!